# Auto converting drawable to png in build time increasing apk size

Tags: android, apk, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

My drawables getting converted to pngs for different screen resulting bigger apk size, any trick to reduce apk size or not converting into png in build time?

My build.gradle android block looks like this :

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    maxProcessCount 4
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.toyanathpatro.gurkha"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    //noinspection HighAppVersionCode
    versionCode 2017063114
    versionName "3.3"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    disable 'RestrictedApi'
}
dataBinding {
    enabled true
}
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
return void
```

}

Comment: You could try using splits in gradle.

Comment: Does that solve the issue with multiple image files for different screen size?

Comment: Splits and ResConfigs can help reduce the app size.

Comment: That is a good idea but That is not the focal point, the thing is I do not want my drawables converted into pngs for every screen size, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your images to WebP format. As staed in Android docs, WebP formatted images are 26% smaller than PNGs. You could check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/convert-webp.html) out to see how to convert images to WebP format. 
Also you can use Splits and ResConfigs to reduce the final APK size.

Reference Documentation:

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/network-xfer.html

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html